# mysql : how do you select blog body that has just an image no text?

Tags: mysql, text, sql-like

I have 80K nodes from my blog and I want to select only the bodies of blog that have image (s) only no text.
I tried

```
 select * from field_data_field_body where (field_body_value like '<img%>' or field_body_value like '<p><img%/></p>');
```

but I want to make sure I grab all the node with image only body.

Is there a better way?

**update**
Here's is some body values example :

```
<img width=\"120\" vspace=\"5\" hspace=\"5\" height=\"90\" border=\"0\" align=\"left\" src=\"/static/video/missiles.jpg\" /> <h2><a href=\"/items/itembody/200410290009\">Some tests value </a></h2>     

<p><img src=\"/static/images/home/205/rove-205.JPG\" /></p>    <--need these 

<img src=\"/static/images/90billion.jpg\" class=\"post-right\" width=\"450\" height=\"246\" /></p>\n<p>The media declared</a> one of the top last night</p>    

while <p><img src=\"/static/images/hornerb.jpg\" width=\"645\" height=\"337\" /></p>\n<p>An independent report has all but destroyed one of the right\'s most cherished \"scandals,\" </p>    

<p><img src=\"/static/images/205/rove-205.JPG\" /></p>    <--need these
```

Answer (score 1):

If your field_body_value is just a long string of HTML that may contain an  tag, and you want to find rows that contain that anywhere within the field, this should work.
You have to wildcard both before and after the value you are looking for because it could appear anywhere within the text.

```
select * from field_data_field_body where field_body_value like '%<img%';
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that query before but it is not restrictive enough. The `%` at the beginning will add `field_body_value` that have non image content (e.g. text).

Comment: If there are values that contain the string “<img” but are not image tags, then yes, they will also be included. So you would have to expand that by something like “%<img src=%“. Perhaps some examples of your data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE body REGEXP '^([[:space:]]*<img[^>]*>)+[[:space:]]*'
```

Some notes:

- Assuming there might be spaces, newlines, etc between img tags I included `[[:space:]]*`
- `[^>]*` eats up anything before the next `>`, thereby not matching non-img tags.
- `^ and`$` "anchor" the string.

It is much more difficult to also allow `<p>`, `<br>`, and other tags that generate only 'whitespace'.  Here's another attempt:

```
WHERE body REGEXP '^([[:space:]]+|<img[^>]*>|<br>|</?p>)+$'
```

Notes:

- It will match a `body` with just whitespace
- This fails to handle `<br >`, `<br/>` and other variants.
- Depending on the collation, it may fail to handle `<BR>`.
- Some of the above are easily fixed.